# Getting Submit button to run code in function in C# using MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't fully understand the Razor Syntax so that is part of my problem but I also feel there is a logic issue with how I am trying to do this.

When I click download I just get  "the resource cannot be found"

Below is my code from the view.

```
 <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.cusName }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.cusName }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.cusName })


        <br />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "RMAFormModelsController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Download" }))
    {
        <div id="convertAboutPageButtonDiv">
            <input type="submit" value="Download to Excel File" />
        </div>
    }
    <br />

    </td>
```

below is the code from the C# function.

```
//Export to excel
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Download()
        {

            List<Lookup> lookupList = new List<Lookup>();
            var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

            grid.DataSource = lookupList;
            grid.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFileName.xlsx");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();

            return View();
        }
```

This all seems like it should work. What am I miss-understanding?

Comment: It seems that you want _RMAFormModels_ without the Controller part and no argiment _id = "download"_ is expected by the Download method

Comment: If I am understanding you correct your saying. Because I don't have an argument and that I should be trying to reference the Model directly? I thought the View has to talk to the controller to pass and take things from the model? Thank you for such a quick response and your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update RMAFormModels instead of RMAFormModelsController in form's html helper.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "RMAFormModels", FormMethod.Post))
   {
       <div id="convertAboutPageButtonDiv">
            <input type="submit" value="Download to Excel File" />
       </div>
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works! Do you mind explaining why it worked? How does calling on the model allow me to run the function in the controller?

Comment: @JonathanGreene Forms syntax is Html.BeginForm(ActionName, Controller Name, Method Type).. So if your controller name is like abccontroller then you need to mention abc inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan, You have 2 issues in your code. First one is you don't have to use complete controller name in html.beginform(). Remove RMAFormModelsController from form and add only RMAFormModels.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "RMAFormModels", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Download" })))
   {
       <div id="convertAboutPageButtonDiv">
            <input type="submit" value="Download to Excel File" />
       </div>
   }
```

And in your beginform you have created new{id="Download"}. So inorder to work it as expected you must have argument called id in your controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Download(string id)
        {
        }
```

Or else you can use @Power answer since he removed your new{id="Download"} from the html.beginform.

Thanks.